# GTK/Linux printing blocks and ignores callback

Tags: linux, printing, gtk, gnome

I want to print out some vectordata using Linux. That's what I already have:

```
GtkPrintOperation *op;

op = gtk_print_operation_new();
gtk_print_operation_set_n_pages(op, 1);
gtk_print_operation_set_unit (op,GTK_UNIT_POINTS);
g_signal_connect (op, "draw_page", G_CALLBACK(draw_page), NULL);
if (data->config.m_printparams==1) 
    gtk_print_operation_run(op, GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_ACTION_PRINT,NULL, NULL);
else
    gtk_print_operation_run (op, GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_ACTION_PRINT_DIALOG,NULL, NULL);
```

`draw_page` of course exists as well:

```
static void draw_page (GtkPrintOperation *operation,GtkPrintContext *context,int page_nr)
{
   GtkPrintSettings *settings;

   cairo_t *cr = gtk_print_context_get_cairo_context (context);
   settings = gtk_print_operation_get_print_settings (operation);
   ...do some printing stuff here...
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work, `gtk_print_operation_run()` blocks forever and `draw_page()` is never called. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.7/gtk3-High-level-Printing-API.html#gtk-print-operation-run) `Normally that this function does not return until the rendering of all pages is complete` Also you can set to be async call as mentioned in the documentation

Comment: OK but rendering of pages never starts - the rendering callback is not called!